# Frame.setAlpha not working from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to dim/blur the background of a custom `PopupWindow`.

My XML file for `ViewPagerActivity` has a `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/Frame"
   android:foreground="#00000000">
   <!-- other many elements -->
</FrameLayout>
```

And, its foreground property is nullified in `ViewPagerActivity` which works fine

```
FrameLayout myFrame = findViewById(R.id.Frame);
myFrame.getForeground().setAlpha(0); //works
```

But my activity has further two fragments. One of them displays a `PopupWindow` and I wish to restore the foreground color so as the PopupWindow has a dimmed background.

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
void showWindow() {
    ViewPagerActivity vpa = new ViewPagerActivity();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //vpa.myFrame.getForeground().setAlpha(220); //not working
    vpa.myFrame.setAlpha((float) 0.8); //not working
    ((ViewPagerActivity) getActivity()).myFrame.setAlpha(0.8f); //not working

    assert inflater != null;
    mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up, null), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(customView.findViewById(R.id.custom_View), Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
}
```

where `activity_view_pager` contains the FrameLayout and `activity_pop_up` is the PopUpWindow drawable. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but the `tempView` you inflate and set the alpha on there is never added to an on-screen hierarchy, so you never see it.

Comment: I need a dimmed background for my PopupWindow. Hence, I set a foreground to my Activity layout but I can't dim it. If I use `myFrame` without inflation, it's null

Comment: `ViewPagerActivity` is the `Activity`? You can't `new` that, either. You could use `getActivity()` in your `Fragment` to get the hosting `Activity` instance, and call a method there to set that alpha on the `FrameLayout` that's already in its layout. As you have it now, you're just creating new instances of both the `Activity` and `FrameLayout` that are never used.

Comment: `getActivity().myFrame` is unresolved symbol whereupon `ViewPagerActivity.myFrame` (without creating instance) is a call from `static` reference to a nn-static object. If I declare `myFrame` to be `static` it is a memory leak.

Comment: `getActivity()` returns an `Activity`, not your specific subclass. You have to cast it. If you just wanna do it directly like that: `((ViewPagerActivity) getActivity()).myFrame.setAlpha(0.8f);`.

Comment: I have removed all instances, it still doesn't work. No error but no change in response either.

Comment: Just tested, and it works for me. Are you sure `myFrame` is pointing to the right thing? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If I remove `myFrame.getForeground().setAlpha(0);`  after assignment in ViewPagerActivity, it gives desired result. So I would say .. yes, it is pointing to the right thing.

Comment: `((ViewPagerActivity) getActivity()).myFrame.getForeground().setAlpha(220);` is to be used not only `setAlpha`

Comment: You have `myFrame.setAlpha(0.8f)` in your snippet, not `myFrame.getForeground().setAlpha(220)`. Anyway, `Drawable` alpha is handled differently than `View` alpha. Set your `foreground` to something non-transparent - e.g., `#77000000` - and test that.